# Set env variables in multiple loops using postman

Tags: automated-tests, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

I want to test the following workflow structure.

in first request script,

```
var st = [1,2,3]
var i = st.length;
for(var j=0; j<i; j++) {
    pm.environment.set("id", st[j]);
    postman.setNextRequest("getNext");
};
```

In getNext pre test script,

```
var id = pm.environment.get("id");
console.log(`Run ${id}`);
```

In console, there is only `Run 3` message is shown.

The problem is that the env variables are overwritten with the last elements. And I can see only the last element of the list and the requests are using the last element.

I would like to know How can I keep the env variables not to be overwritten?

**EDIT**
I remove my messy question and add simple workflow.

Comment: Not sure to understand from your pseudo code example. Could you pls add real code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `postman.setNextRequest()` is always executed at the end of the
> current request. This means that if you put this function before other
> code blocks anywhere in pre-request or test script, these blocks will
> still execute.

That means, the loop runs 3x, and only at the very end, when the complete script is finished, it calls the `postman.setNextRequest()`, when `id` has the value `3`.

See [documentation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/building-workflows/#:%7E:text=setNextRequest()%20is%20always%20executed,source%20of%20your%20collection%20run) for more details.

Found this blog post, that's explaining how you can achieve it: https://ambertests.com/2019/01/28/postman-how-to-dynamic-iteration-within-a-collection/